# Haskell Chesshs and Array Error How To Define `board :: Array (Int, Int) (Maybe Piece)`

Tags: arrays, haskell

I am trying to build a Board in the library [chesshs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/chesshs).

```hs
-- from chesshs source code:

data Board = Board { turn :: Color
                   , castlingAvail :: String
                   , enpassant :: Maybe (Int, Int)
                   , board :: Array (Int, Int) (Maybe Piece)
                   } deriving (Eq)
```

so I am trying to create a Board with the following:

```hs
*MyLib Data.Array Chess> Board {
  turn = White
, castlingAvail = ""
, enpassant = Nothing
, board = Array (0,0) (Just (Piece White Pawn))
}
```

but I get the following error, as if Array doesn't exist, Strange because is what it appears as type signature in the board parameter as per chesshs source code:

```
<interactive>:103:71: error:
    • Data constructor not in scope:
        Array :: (a0, b0) -> Maybe Piece -> Array (Int, Int) (Maybe Piece)
    • Perhaps you meant variable ‘array’ (imported from Data.Array)
```

so I try substituting `Array` for `array` (not quite sure why Array doesn't work and if array is just the way to create an Array)

```hs
*MyLib Data.Array Chess Chess.PGN> Board {
  turn = White
, castlingAvail = ""
, enpassant = Nothing
, board = array (0,0) (Just (Piece White Pawn))
}
```

but it doesn't work and I receive this error message:

```
<interactive>:104:84: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[((Int, Int), Maybe Piece)]’
                  with actual type ‘Maybe Piece’
    • In the second argument of ‘array’, namely
        ‘(Just (Piece White Pawn))’
      In the ‘board’ field of a record
      In the expression:
        Board
          {turn = White, castlingAvail = "", enpassant = Nothing,
           board = array (0, 0) (Just (Piece White Pawn))}
```

Which make sense because checking the `array` type

```
array :: Ix i => (i, i) -> [(i, e)] -> Array i e
```

so I try the following:

```hs
*MyLib Data.Array Chess> Board {
  turn = White
, castlingAvail = ""
, enpassant = Nothing
, board = array (0,0) [((0,0), (Just (Piece White Pawn)))]
}
```

which gives me this error:

```
<interactive>:108:78: error:
    • No instance for (Num (Int, Int)) arising from the literal ‘0’
    • In the expression: 0
      In the first argument of ‘array’, namely ‘(0, 0)’
      In the ‘board’ field of a record
```

Which leaves me very confused.. not quite sure why ghci interaction drives me to use a type different from what it appears in the source code of chesshs Board and why it anyway drives me to an error that I don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array i e` is a type. It's defined in a module which does *not* export its data constructors, so we don't get access to those. This is unlike the `Maybe a` type for which we get access to the `Nothing` and `Just` constructors.

Hence, to create an array value we need to rely on the functions exported by the module. There is indeed a function for that, named `array`. This function is sometimes referred to as a "smart" constructor, since unlike a (regular) constructor it performs some sanity checks before constructing the value.

Anyway, it is meant to be used like this:

```
array (startPos, endPos)
      [ (startPos, value0), (nextPos, value1), ..., (endPos, valueLast) ]
```

We provide a pair with the first and last valid array indices/positions. We then provide a list of pairs. associating each valid index/position to its value.

In your case, if you board only contains position `(0,0)` (should it be so?) then it should be created as

```
array ((0,0),(0,0)) [ ((0,0), Just (Piece White Pawn)) ]
```

If instead you need to create a 8x8 board, you will need a longer list for that.

```
array ((0,0),(7,7)) [ ((0,0), Just (Piece White Pawn)) , ....
-- add all other positions, possibly with Nothing values
```

If you need to place only a few pieces in a large board, it might be more convenient to simply create an empty board and then update it with the few pieces. E.g.

```
let emptyB = array ((0,0),(7,7)) [ ((x,y), Nothing) | x<-[0..7], y<-[0..7] ]
    myB = emptyB // [ ((5,5), Just (Piece White Pawn)) ]
in ...
```

Here I used the `//` operator to create a new board with the same pieces as `emptyB`, except for those positions and values in the list.

Comment: Odd. `MArray` offers `newArray` for making a fresh array full of a default value, but `IArray` doesn't offer anything similar. The closest thing that didn't require you to repeat the array bounds twice would be something like `accumArray (flip const) Nothing ((0, 0), (7, 7)) [((5,5), Just (Piece White Pawn))]`.

Comment: I see! so my confusion was that in the source code they show the Array type `i e`... and then I was trying to use `array` as if it was that, while is instead a different type signature `(i,i) [(i,e)]`  that then creates the type that board in Board wants `i e`. Thanks! real helpful